# MySQL REGEXP query

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to select all the rows in a table from a database that has a the following structure:

```
<tr>
<td>
<p><strong>Completion Date:</strong></p>
</td>
<td>
<p>April, 2012</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

But the month and year could be different.

Here is my current query statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `content` REGEXP "<tr>\r\n<td>\r\n<p><strong>Completion Date:</strong></p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<p>April, 2012</p>\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>"
```

Currently this will only pull the rows that have April, 2012 which is what I expect it to pull. I tried replacing the month with: ^[A-Za-z]$ but this did not work nor any other combination I tired.

Could someone help with the correct regular expression?

Thanks,

-M

Comment: Use [A-Za-z]* without carret and dollar sign to match it.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but _ewww!_ That's a _horrible_ way to store data in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the results you are looking for. Note how you need the star, which means 0 or more `[a-zA-Z]`, and zero or more `[0-9]` characters.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `content` REGEXP "<tr>\r\n<td>\r\n<p><strong>Completion Date:</strong></p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<p>[a-zA-Z]*, [0-9]*</p>\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>"
```

The caret `^` and dollar sign `$` match the beginning and the end of the string. Since the date is not at the beginning, these would not match for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Oh I see interesting! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the question marks don't belong there; I've edited the answer to remove them. (In PCRE-style regexps, `*?` means the same thing as `*` except that it tries to match as few characters as possible, but as far as I can tell, [MySQL's regexp engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) doesn't support such ungreedy matching. In any case, even if it worked, it would make no difference here.)

Comment: Ah I've been in the habit of using non-greedy * matches in perl style. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

`^[A-Za-z]$` will match a single alphabetic character on a line (`^` for beginning of string, `$` for end of string).

You might have more luck with something like: `[A-Z][a-z]*,\s*[0-9]{4}`.  To explain:

- `[A-Z]` - 1 capital letter
- `[a-z]*` - any number of lowercase letters (including 0 of them)
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - any number of spaces (including 0 of them)
- `[0-9]{4}` - exactly 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

If it's just month and year you can do:

`[a-zA-Z]+, \d{4}`

Granted, this will take ANY word and ANY 4 digit year. If you wanted to add more checks, it could be:

`(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December), (19|20)\d{2}`

This new regex would match from the possible valid Months, and also check if the year is 19xx or 20xx.